# Configure Google App Engine SSL for custom domains

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, dns

The problem:

I have configured GAE with a custom domain with SSL and **it does not work for the root domain**: https://example.com

I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

These work fine:

- **www.example.com** (over **https**) and
- **example.com** (over **http**)

In Google Apps admin -> Security -> SSL for Custom Domains:

I have uploaded an SSL certificate which should work for both cases:

```
Subject Alternative Names
DNS Name:www.example.com
DNS Name:example.com
```

The Serving mode is SNI Only.
Assigned URL is https://www.example.com and there are no other matching URLs - I believe this is the problem and as far as I understood the docs I should to Google Developers Console to add more URLs.

In Google Developers Console -> Compute -> App Engine -> Settings -> Custom Domains:
In step 1 I have verified my domain.
In Step 2 I have added a few subdomains like **www.example.com** and the root domain **example.com**.

Since all these URLs are reachable over http I guess this particular configuration is fine - I just can't find a way to get these to show as **matching URLs** in the SSL configuration ! 
Any ideas what might be wrong here ?

My thanks for the help !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, SSL for the "naked" domain (example.com) is not yet supported by Google Apps.  You can configure Google Apps to redirect from the naked domain to a subdomain (www.example.com), but as you noticed, it won't do it over SSL, even if the naked domain is mentioned in the certificate.  It'll only use the certificate for traffic for the subdomains that are assigned applications (the "matching URLs").

I agree it's a gap in the feature.  As a partial solution, if you redirect http://example.com to http://www.example.com, you can then redirect again to https://www.example.com with the App Engine configuration (`secure: always`).

Comment: Thanks for the help, Dan! Do you have any suggestion how I could redirect from example.com to www.example.com ? Is there a config somewhere ?

Comment: @Daniel your domain registrar may offer this redirect facility, but I agree it's far from ideal.  In the meantime, you may like to star [Issue 10802](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10802) to see if this gets progressed.

Comment: Google Apps also offers this redirect feature. Sign in to admin.google.com with your domain admin account, open More Controls, select Domains. With the primary domain added, you should be able to set up the redirect to the subdomain in here.  It occurs to me that I might have misspoken about whether the redirect supports https, so let me know if that works for you.  The important bit is Google Apps doesn't support serving an app from the naked domain.  Cloud Platform *does* support serving from the naked domain, but not via SSL, yet.

Comment: @DanSanderson: I get a server error right now when I try to enable the redirect from the naked domain to www - I'll try again but it seems that it should solve my issue - thanks !